# How do I change parents of one entity in GAE datastore using JPA?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

How can I remove one entity from its parent and add it to another parent?
Here is my code. `Team` has a `List<Player>`, and `Player` has an association to its parent:

```
Player player = entityManager.find(Player.class, playerKey);
Team team1 = player.getTeam();
team1.getPlayers().remove(player); // this action will cascade the deletion of player;
entityManager.merge(team1);

Team team2 = entityManager.find(Team.class, team2Key);
team2.getPlayers().add(player);
entityManager.merge(team2);
```

This is what I want to do, but will result in failure. I thought I could use [`entityManager.detach(player)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29) to use in the other team, but this method is not available in the GAE jar (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this is a GAE "owned" relation? In which case you likely can't change the "owner" since GAE will have put it into the Key of the Player.

If instead you make the relation as "unowned" (like all relations for all other datastores) you can obviously reparent it. You need to be using [GAE/J JPA plugin](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/) v2.x for this.

And yes GAE/J JPA does support JPA2, if you're using the [GAE/J JPA plugin](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/) v2.x (with [DataNucleus 3.x](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/index.html))

Comment: I'm not using JPA plugin v2.x, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Additionally, 99% of my queries gets the team and iterates over the players, so making them unowned would have some additional cost, right?

Comment: yes, unowned will likely have some (small?) cost. With v1.x I see no real alternative, other than having a clone() method on Player that you add to the new Team. v2.x also allows having embedded collection of Player in Team, which reduces the read time.